# Retrieve a facebook secret group feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm building a PHP application on a website to allow members of a secret Facebook group to retrieve all the YouTube links posted on the group wall. To do that I need to retrieve the feed of the group which I did using open graph. I generate an `access_token` thanks to graph API explorer and I managed to display the feed but it relies on the `access_token` which is eventually going to expire.

How can I do to be able to call the API's functions at any time with a valid `access_token`?

I was thinking about asking the visitors to connect with their Facebook account onto the application so that they can make a request with their own token.

Do you have leads on how I could do that?

Comment: For your last question – start reading docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks i just created a dum app on facebook to allow oauth on my website and that did the trick.